# Why isn't this simple function working?

Tags: php

I didn't want to keep repeating the same select query, so I wrote this function. But it doesn't work:

```
function select($what, $table) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT $what FROM $table");
}
select(*, products);
```

Comment: did you try using mysql_error() func ?

Comment: This is an SQL injection nightmare.

Comment: @Bill Karwin I always sanitize my input with mysql_real_escape_string I just didn't write that here :)

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is for strings, not table names, column names, SQL keywords, expressions, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to enclose your arguments in quotes.
2. You should return the query pointer afterwards.
3. You should quote-escape the values to avoid SQL injection.

```
function select($what, $table) {
    $what = mysql_real_escape_string($what);
    $table = mysql_real_escape_string($table);
    return mysql_query("SELECT '$what' FROM `$table`;");
}
$query = select('*', 'products');
```

For debugging:

```
function select($what, $table) {
    $what = mysql_real_escape_string($what);
    $table = mysql_real_escape_string($table);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT '$what' FROM `$table`;") or die(mysql_error());
    return $query;
}
$query = select('*', 'products');
```

Comment: I copied your code exactly and it still doesn't work, gives this error:


Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping_cart\product.php on line 22

Comment: It's because `mysql_query()` is returning `false`.

Comment: Please, replace addslashes with mysql_real_escape_string. See also the documentation of addslashes http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php -1 from me until you fix that...

Comment: Also you can't put a table name in single-quotes.

Comment: This works now:

function select($what, $table) {
    return $query = mysql_query("SELECT $what FROM $table");
}
$query = select("*", "products");

Comment: Yes, but you didn't escape your input data, which could very easily lead to SQL injection, which leads to password stealing or database destruction.

Comment: The `*` doesn't belong inside quotes.  And neither would a column name if you passed that.

Answer (score 2):

you need to return $query

```
function select($what, $table) {
    return $query = mysql_query("SELECT $what FROM $table");
}
$query = select(*, products);
```

Then $query will have the result source of your query, which you would then use mysql_fetch_xxx or whatever on.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is:

```
function select($what, $table) {
    return mysql_query("SELECT $what FROM `$table`");
}
$query = select('*', 'products');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments should be strings (ie. `select('*', 'products')`)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because $query is discarded after the function ends? I don't have much experience with SQL, but this would look better to me:

```
function select($what, $table) {
    return mysql_query("SELECT $what FROM $table");
}
select("*", "products");
```

Oh, and "*" and "products" need to be strings.